# What is the minimum MTU size?

Tags: mtu

The [maximum size is 1500 Bytes](http://www.linfo.org/mtu.html).  Is there a lower limit? 1? 64?  Must it be a multiple of two?  Is there somewhere I can look to learn more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, **IPv4 implementations** require a minimum MTU of 68 bytes per [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791).

See Peter's answer for more detail.

Comment: You contradict yourself. The quote says "up to 576", not "at least 576".

Comment: Edited answer for clarity.  Devices can receive packets with smaller MTU's, but per the RFC, 576 bytes was the right size to use.  Most OSs enforce a number around 576, it varies slightly - so there's really no reason to send smaller than necessary.

Comment: This answer is wrong, it's confusing datagram size with MTU.

Comment: Yup, you're right - edited my answer.  Thanks for catching that @PeterGreen.

Answer (score 9):

The minimum MTU for IPv4 is 68 bytes. Specifically from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791

> Every internet module must be able to forward a datagram of 68
> octets without further fragmentation.  This is because an internet
> header may be up to 60 octets, and the minimum fragment is 8 octets.

However such a low MTU would be extremely inefficient.

IPv6 sets a much higher minimum of 1280 bytes and requires links that can't support that MTU to provide a link-specific fragmentation and reassembly layer.  From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460

> IPv6 requires that every link in the internet have an MTU of 1280
> octets or greater.  On any link that cannot convey a 1280-octet
> packet in one piece, link-specific fragmentation and reassembly must
> be provided at a layer below IPv6.

Presumablly the motivation is to stop low MTU links from driving inefficiency across the network. I assume 1280 bytes was chosen to allow for a packet to be wrapped in some encapsulation/tunneling crap and still fit in a standard ethernet frame.

Comment: So are there some reasons in a real-world IPv4 networks to set MTU to `68` or e.g. `200` or something very small relative to the usual `1500`?

Comment: IPv4 was designed in an era when connections were much slower. If you are running over a 1200 baud modem then a 1500 byte packet will block the link for over a second, this is generally not desirable.

Comment: Thanks! In other words MTU value is determined by the physical transmission medium (which in turn is determined by the devices). So if there are some slow devices with corresponding link-layer protocol between them - there could be some small MTU value. Isn't it? But I'm not sure that this is the case in modern IP-networks.

Comment: The physical transmission medium does not directly determine the MTU, but it does have an impact on what MTU values are likely to be considered sensible by a designer.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if it is the lowest but can has a MTU of 8 bytes. It can't be used directly for IP packets.

Comment: "MTU" is an IETF term for IP networks, so your answer doesn't make sense. 8 bytes cannot work as it can't even carry an IPv4 header, let alone any payload.

Comment: @Zac67 Linux gives also a MTU for socketCAN devices. Of course it makes sense. From Wikipedia: "Maximum transmission unit, the size of the largest packet that a network protocol can transmit" There is nothing about IP. The OP didn't say anything about IP.

Comment: I'm afraid, SocketCAN and hosts are nothing that is on-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. And the WP article about MTU talks at length about the *Internet Protocol* which I would see as implied unless the OP indicates otherwise.

Comment: @Zac67 Read it. Don't see any indication why it shouldn't be on topic. It is about networks and CAN is a Network. And again, the OP didn't say anything about IP. I wouldn't imply that, maybe you are in a bubble where you almost only use IP and related stacks?

Comment: While I wouldn't strictly say CAN is off-topic here, it's a fringe topic here. If you check the [help/on-topic], it very clearly states *Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment* and elaborates on the various scenarios. So, if someone mentions *MTU* without any more context, IP **is** implied. If you need to discuss further, I'd suggest putting that on [meta].